# Enabling PostgreSQL support in PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, php-extension

I'm having a terribly difficult time getting the command "pg_connect()" to work properly on my Mac. I'm currently writing a PHP script (to be executed from console) to read a PostgreSQL database and email a report.

I've gone into my `php.ini` file and added

```
extension=pgsql.so
```

But, I'm met with the following error.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in... (blah file here)

When running `phpinfo()`, I see nothing about PostgreSQL, so what is my issue here?

Comment: have you installed the proper drivers?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The PHP version that comes bundled with OS X doesn't include PostgreSQL. You'll have to compile the extension yourself. Here are some instructions:

1. Find your version of PHP: `php -v`.
2. Download the version of PHP that matches yours: `curl -O http://us.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.3.tar.gz`. (This example downloads PHP 5.3.3 but this must match your version)
3. Extract the archive you downloaded: `tar -xzvf php-5.3.3.tar.gz`
4. Change to the PostgreSQL's extension directory: `cd php-5.3.3/ext/pgsql/`
5. Type `phpize`.
6. Type `./configure`.
7. Type `make`.
8. Type `sudo make install`.
9. Add the extension to you `php.ini` file by adding `extension=pgsql.so`. (You may already have done this)
10. Restart Apache.

**Update for OS X Mountain Lion**
Apple has removed `autoconf` from the newer versions of XCode so the procedure above will fail at #5. To solve that problem:

1. Type `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"`.
2. Type `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/Cellar`.
3. Type `brew update`.
4. Type `brew install autoconf`.

That should install `autoconf` and allow you to install the module using the instructions above.

Comment: Thanks for the steps, but unfortunately I'm getting stuck at step 6. With the following error. `configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path`

Comment: Fixed: Just had to specify --with-pgsql=/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/ at the end of the configure statement. And also, I added pgsql.so, not pcntl.so. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jordan Scales - It's looking for the files in "/usr", "/usr/local", and "/usr/local/pgsql". If PostgreSQL is installed somewhere else on your system, you'll have to change `./configure` to `./configure  --with-pgsql=/path/to/pgsql`.

Comment: @Jordan Scales - No problem. You solved the problem before I had a chance to finish writing my answer!

Comment: Looks like they moved the location for older versions.  Try http://us.php.net/releases/ to find the URL for the version you're looking for.

Comment: I am running Mavericks, but this is probably applicable to other versions. My php.ini was not present, and instead a php.ini.default was in place. This file isn't automatically picked up by php, so I did a 'sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini' then restarted apache which is done using 'sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart'.

Comment: I am using yosemite... big trouble over here!!! This worked perfectly, but only after i have installed XCODE command line tools though terminal command **xcode-select --install**. So, first reinstall -select, then follow the instructions of this post.

Comment: If you get an error about "error: use of undeclared identifier 'HASH_KEY_NON_EXISTENT'", edit the pgsql.c file, and change the spelling of EXISTENT to EXISTANT - with an "A" in all places HASH_KEY_NON_EXISTENT  exists.  Then run make again.

Comment: I was not able to get past @JordanScales error. Installing postgres with brew worked.. The app did not do it.

Comment: In El Capitan works, but first i needed do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled

Comment: On MacOS Sonoma 14.0 worked for me with curl -OL http://us.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.3.tar.gz

Answer (score 36):

If you use home `brew`, you can solve this with a command as simple as:

`brew install php55-pdo-pgsql`

for other php version, search with:

`brew search pgsql`

Comment: This is the better answer (+1). The currently accepted answer suggests to use `brew` to install `autoconf` and then to compile PHP from source code. Which is unnecessary work, because you can directly install PostgreSQL, PHP and the `phpXX-pdo-pgsql` packages - all using [brew](http://brew.sh) for Mac OSX.

Comment: I tried this and the install is successful (I see pdo_pgsql in `php -i`) but I still get `pg_connect() not found` errors..

Comment: Actually, this is a better answer. Because almost all developers use some kind of packet manager these days.

Answer (score 8):

### This worked for me with OSX 10.9.4 «**Mavericks**»

**Install sources**

Download the PHP source code. Unlike on Mountain Lion, you don’t get any headers preinstalled to link against so need to put it in /usr/include/php. Mavericks ships with PHP 5.4.17, but the latest 5.4.x source from php.net should do:

```
tar -jxvf php-5.4.20.tar.bz2
sudo mkdir -p /usr/include
sudo mv php-5.4.20 /usr/include/php
```

**Configure PHP**

```
cd /usr/include/php
./configure --without-iconv
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

**Building a module**

I needed the pdo_pgsql module - the same pattern should apply to just about any module assuming you have the necessary dependencies installed:

```
cd ext/pdo_pgsql
```

In my case I had the following error:

Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script. ERROR:
`phpize' failed

So I had to use this command:

```
brew install autoconf
```

Then:

```
phpize
```

After that I tried to do:
./configure

but I had the next problem:

checking for pg_config... not found configure: error: Cannot find
libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path

So the solution was to specify correct PostgreSQL installation path:

```
./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/
make
sudo make install
```

That copies pdo_pgsql.so to /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525.

Then simply add

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so to /etc/php.ini
```

Run `php -m` to confirm everything went to plan.

Comment: Your approach also works for Yosemite. The only caveats are: to use `./configure --with-pgsql=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/` in case of PHP 5.5.20; add `extension=pgsql.so` to /etc/php.ini (originally php.ini.default).

Answer (score 7):

For those who installed php7/ngix/postgres with homebrew

You can install the PostgreSQL module with:

```
brew install php70-pdo-pgsql
```

After that, you have to restart the php service:

```
brew services restart php70
```

Answer (score 3):

OS X El Capitan users can simply upgrade their version of PHP 5.6.  This is a one liner that will do that.

curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

Answer (score 3):

For `php56` via brew:

```
brew install php56-pdo-pgsql
```

Comment: I'm on Sierra, and this didn't work for me.  Install completed, but no `pdo_pgsql` appears in in phpinfo()

Comment: Hi @Francis, did you check by `php -i | grep pdo_pgsql` in terminal ? Or restart your webserver to see in browser. Refer to my screen shot: http://prnt.sc/dcmkcp

Comment: Hi - found the issue.  Sierra Server of course has at least two PHP instances with their own php.ini files; one in `/private/etc` and the other in `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/private/etc/php.ini`.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I intent to tell you to make sure whether php version and its location are correct. Better you should use php with `homebrew`, not the default one. Because its config will lose when you upgrade your MacOS

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL by default is installed in a unusual place on MAC OS X:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3
```

Given the location above you can type this:

```
./configure --with-pgsql=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I killed the whole day trying to make it work on El Capitan after I made an upgrade yesterday and it turned out that I forgot to modify `httpd.conf` and change the path from the default php module (version 5.5.27) to the one I installed (version 5.6.14). This should be done in `httpd.conf` by modifying your default `LoadModule php5_module` path to `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. 
Just decided to leave it here as the potential solution for those who upgrade their OS or just the PHP version and face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having openssl error while `make` here is the solution

OSX uses openssl 0.98 while installer is searching for 1.0.0

refer this link for instructions

[psycopg2 installation error - Library not loaded: libssl.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365619/psycopg2-installation-error-library-not-loaded-libssl-dylib)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded PostgreSQL for Mac, and used the stack builder after installation to standup the entire EnterpriseDB Apache/PHP stack end-to-end.  I mention this as a possible time saving option, probably not ideal for all situations.  Should work OK if the apache and postgres shipped with Mac OS X were never started.

To keep existing apache hosted applications (i.e. pre-PostgreSQL install legacy) stable, I would just install the newer EnterpriseDB apache on port 81 (stackbuilder  will prompt for new port if legacy apache instance is already running).  Then, use mod_proxy in httpd.conf for the apache running on port 80 to provide seamless user experience to applications hosted on PostgreSQL.