# psycopg2 installation error - Library not loaded: libssl.dylib

Tags: python, virtualenv, psycopg2

I try to install `psycopg2` in a virtualenv using `pip`, the compilation looks ok, it says "Successfully installed psycopg2", but when I try to import it in python interpreter (in virtualenv), it indicates error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/sites/env/trackmap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/sites/env/trackmap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/sites/env/trackmap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _psycopg.so requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8
```

The thing is I install it successfully using `pip` in my other virtual env before, like, several weeks ago, and get it working with the `postgresql` on my mac. I am wondering if this is a problem of compiler? I saw some warnings like `shortens from 64-bit to 32-bit` during the installation of psycopg2. My compiler is `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`, default one on mac os x lion.

I see several posts related to `psycopg2` install but most of them are solved by installing in a virtual env. So...could anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you! Really appreciated.

p.s. If you need the compilation log of installing psycopg2 please let me know, I didn't paste it here because it is too long.

Answer (score 102):

Does the error say `libssl.dylib` version is too old?

On my mac, the error is that `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib` is too old for pyscopg to use. The `openssl` package used by mac is 0.98, while pyscopg needs 1.0.0 or later version.

My solution is this:

1. install openssl from brew

   ```
   $ brew install openssl
   ```
2. copy `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` and `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` from `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c` to `/usr/lib/`

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib
   $ sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
   ```
3. in `/usr/lib` directory, make a softlink `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib`. You may have to remove the existing links.

   ```
   $ sudo rm libssl.dylib libcrypto.dylib
   $ sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib
   $ sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib
   ```

Comment: FYI from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error - "Per Purrell's answer, make sure you include the -fs flags when you use the ln command, which helps ensure that the libraries don't go missing for a short period of time."

Comment: Thank you for this! I had the linking error but totally unrelated to postgresql, took me forever to find an easy solution.

Comment: Steps explained pretty nicely at this link http://mithun.co/hacks/library-not-loaded-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib-issue-in-mac/

Comment: Just a note: I had `openssl/1.0.2h_1/`, but the files I needed to move were still `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` and `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`. Everything worked great, though I did need [help with sudo permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled) as well.

Comment: How about this?
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

Comment: In recent versions of MacOS, `/usr/lib` is protected by SIP. Following these instructions with `/usr/local/lib` worked for me.

Answer (score 56):

I think in Mac we need:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

on m1:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
```

Comment: Great answer. Solved the build problem.

Comment: Greate this works on MacOS Big sur 11.0.1

Comment: On Mac 11 this answer solves the problem. Not sure, but you might need to install postgres sql before installing psycopg2.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Doesn't involve messing with system libssl or installing extra files. Note: this assumes you've already installed a newer version of openssl using Homebrew

Comment: if you are on a Mac with m1 chip. ```export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"```

Comment: Thank you, this worked on my M1 in 2023 on macOS Ventura 13.2.1.

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar issue.  I had used Anaconda to install python and a number of packages and then later used pip to install psycopg2.  I was able to fix the error by uninstalling psycopg2 and reinstalled it with the conda package manager instead of pip.

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
conda install psycopg2
```

Comment: Such an easy thing for those of us with Anaconda on El Captian (thank you [new SIP](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/what-is-sip-in-osx-10-11-el-capitan/)). I can't believe I wasted my time with anything else.

Comment: I wish we could bring this up to top.

Comment: Oh my I cannot thank you enough. I was trying other methods, and only this helps me!

Comment: I have uninstalled Anaconda and this error is happening to me. I there any alternative?

Comment: Worked for me!! So much simplier than everything else I found!

Comment: Tried everything else but this was the trick that worked for me

Answer (score 24):

On OSX 10.11+ (El Capitan or later) solution with replacing symlinks (see above - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911870/565525) `sudo rm libssl.dylib libcrypto.dylib` reports `Operation not permitted`. Solution that worked for me was:

```
brew install openssl
```

Find where openssl brew libs are located, start searching from directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl`. In my case it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib`

Finally set up DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, i.e. add a line like this into .bash_profile :

```
# replace location of lib files with folder name you found in previous step
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib
```

restart shell, or just `source ~/.bash_profile` and test if it works:

```
$ python -c"import psycopg2  ;   print('psycopg2 is now ok')"
```

Comment: Or generically: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib`

Answer (score 13):

Thanks @khrf for your answer.

If you are using the postgres system installer (instead of Postgres.app), use:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib
```

which can be placed in your `~/.bash_profile` if you want to avoid typing it every time.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. Instead I try to place to `~/.bash_profile` : `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` , which it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgresApp, set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable accrordingly, e.g.:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ ../venv/bin/python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in ~/.bash_profile

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

The below method works for me.

```bash
brew install zlib
brew install bzip2
brew install openssl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/bzip2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/bzip2/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours troubleshooting, the following line added to my `.zshrc` file helped me out

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Find where your libssl and libcrypto files are and set the LIBRARY_PATH in your zshrc file would work.

References:
[Add library search path to clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997218/add-library-search-path-to-clang)
https://mithun.co/hacks/library-not-loaded-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib-issue-in-mac/