# Scrapy start project ends with ImportError: No module named spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a new environment with

```
conda create -n scraping python=2.7
```

I activate this environment with

```
source activate scraping
```

Then I proceed to install scrapy with (-n scraping doesn't seem necessary anymore, but I added it just in case)

```
conda install scrapy -n scraping
```

I now have the following installed

```
 % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/alexis/anaconda3/envs/scraping:
#
cffi                      1.1.2                    py27_0
cryptography              0.9.2                    py27_0
cssselect                 0.9.1                    py27_0
enum34                    1.0.4                    py27_0
idna                      2.0                      py27_0
ipaddress                 1.0.7                    py27_0
ipython                   3.2.1                    py27_0
libxml2                   2.9.2                         0
libxslt                   1.1.28                        2
lxml                      3.4.4                    py27_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py27_0
openssl                   1.0.1k                        1
pip                       7.1.0                    py27_0
pyasn1                    0.1.7                    py27_0
pycparser                 2.14                     py27_0
pyopenssl                 0.14                     py27_0
python                    2.7.10                        0
python.app                1.2                      py27_4
queuelib                  1.2.2                    py27_0
readline                  6.2                           2
scrapy                    0.24.4                   py27_0
setuptools                18.0.1                   py27_0
six                       1.9.0                    py27_0
sqlite                    3.8.4.1                       1
tk                        8.5.18                        0
twisted                   15.2.1                   py27_0
w3lib                     1.8.1                    py27_1
zlib                      1.2.8                         0
zope.interface            4.1.2                    py27_1
```

(I also installed ipython)

Now when I try to start a project I get

```
 % scrapy startproject megadeluxe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexis/anaconda3/envs/scraping/bin/scrapy", line 4, in     <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Users/alexis/anaconda3/envs/scraping/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
ImportError: No module named spiders
```

Looking at the content of `scraping/bin/scrapy` I see no file named spiders.py and if I grep for `class Spider` I get no such class anywhere.

Did I do something wrong with the conda install at first? I install python 2.7, which is the requirement.

`which openssl` returns (I think that it's fine)
    /Users/alexis/anaconda3/envs/scraping/bin/openssl

lxml is installed as we can see from `conda list`

I'm a little clueless here.

---

[Edit]
As mentioned in the comments, I was not using the latest version of scrap. This does not explain the error, but I proceeded to install the latest version (1.0) with pip (as of this writing conda only install version 0.24).
After doing so, starting a project would spit something out, ending with `Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

Looking this up on stack overflow returned me this link
[Cannot Set Up a Scrapy Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320585/cannot-set-up-a-scrapy-project)

The answer given by Joe Hooper solved my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26961576/2883980

After all this I now have a solution, but have no clue as to the root reason.

I will put this here so other may find this useful (because I had no idea what DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was used for)

`man dyld`

> DESCRIPTION
>         The dynamic linker uses the following environment variables.
>         They affect any program that uses the dynamic linker.
>
> ```
>   DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>          This is a colon separated list of directories that contain 
>          frameworks.  The  dynamic  linker searches  these  
>          directories  before  it searches for the framework by its 
>          install name.  It allows you to test new versions of 
>          existing frameworks. (A framework is  a  library  install
>          name  that  ends  in the form XXX.framework/Versions/YYY/XXX 
>          or XXX.framework/XXX, where XXX and YYY are any name.)
>
>          For each framework that a program uses, the dynamic linker 
>          looks for the framework  in  each directory  in 
>          DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH in turn. If it looks in all the 
>          directories and can't find the framework, it searches the 
>          directories in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in turn. If it  still  
>          can't find   the   framework,   it   then  searches 
>          DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH  and  DYLD_FALL-
>          BACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.
>
>          Use the -L option to otool(1).  to discover the frameworks 
>          and  shared  libraries  that  the executable is linked 
>          against.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have the scrapy version 0.24.4 installed. Any reasons you're not running the new version 1.0 ?

I believe Scrapy.spiders is a 1.0 class, and not a 0.24 one. I would try to get the really last version installed in your environment, and see if this works.

Comment: conda installs this version by default it seems. See my edit following your suggestion.

Comment: I think I went to the bottom of this. It seems there were quite a lot of changes in the structure of the scrapy library. Some imports that used to work, do not work anymore.
from scrapy.spiders import Spider ==> this is based on Scrapy 1.0 strcuture.

If you wanted to run the same imports but with version 0.24, it should have been as follow:
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Spider

Answer (score -1):

I was working on exactly the same task as you do.

I followed the steps in here to create an environment:

[Create the environment](http://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)

And here to activate my environment:

[Activate the newly created environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

I was working these out with anaconda command prompt.

I installed `Scrapy` a long time ago and therefore when I create the environment, scrapy is already there.

Currently I am having problems with importing items.py :
[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493417/scrapy-import-module-items-error)

Let me know if I could help further.