# Creating Python scrapy project yields: File "<stdin>", line 1 error

Tags: python, scrapy

Windows 10, Command Line Terminal, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

New to Python & following tutorial instructions here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Steps:

1. Downloaded Anaconda
2. Installed scrapy package through Anaconda Navigator
3. Opened terminal
4. cd c:\Anaconda
5. python
6. scrapy startproject tutorial

Yields this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
scrapy startproject tutorial
Syntax Invalid Syntax
```

See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17d3r1hzt02pp2k/Screenshot%202017-11-08%2013.41.06.png?dl=0

I've run globals() to see that Scrapy appears to be running correctly.

I've also try running this command from c:\Anaconda directory.

```
python scrapy startproject tutorial
```

Which yielded this error:

```
python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'scrapy'
```

There may also be an issue with Anaconda & Scrapy ([Cannot Set Up a Scrapy Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320585/cannot-set-up-a-scrapy-project))
though, to my knowledge, I installed correctly using the recommended method from scrapy.org.

Comment: I don't think Python is activated if I leave that out"'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `scrapy startproject tutorial` from terminal, the scrapy executable file will be executed. So first, find out where the scrapy executable file is located, change to that directory(`c:\Anaconda directory` for example) and run the command:

`scrapy startproject tutorial`

or run `scrapy` from a absolute path like this:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/scrapy startproject tutorial`

or like this:

`c:/path/scrapy.exe scrapy startproject tutorial`

Comment: `c:\Anaconda\pkgs\scrapy-1.4.0-py36h764da0a_1\Scripts>scrapy startproject tutorial`  
  
`Unable to create process using 'c:\Anaconda\pkgs\scrapy-1.4.0-py36h764da0a_1\python.exe c:\Anaconda\pkgs\scrapy-1.4.0-py36h764da0a_1\Scripts\scrapy-script.py startproject tutorial'`

Comment: Thanks, the 1st suggestion yielded the above but the 2nd suggestion worked out.