# Install MySQLdb with Anaconda

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, anaconda

I "successfully" installed MySQLdb using:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

But when I use the terminal to check, "import MySQLdb" throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in 
>       import _mysql
>   ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
>     Reason: image not found

I'm assuming this is due to some issue with linking, but I don't know what to do.

--- I'm on a Mac. ---

Comment: seems like you don't have libmysqlclient-dev installed, take a look here http://mysql-python.blogspot.in/2012/11/is-mysqldb-hard-to-install.html

Comment: I've installed mysql using homebrew. That worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYsql-python is a wrapper around MySQL client libraries. Here, you seem to lack SSL libraries. Try installing libssl (if you're on a Debian/Ubuntu/Mint)

`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0`

Comment: I'm on a mac. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: This got me on the right track. I was just missing a dependency. I implemented the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365619/psycopg2-installation-error-library-not-loaded-libssl-dylib

The only difference was that I had 1.0.1h installed instead of 1.0.1c.

Comment: You should avoid 1.0.1c, as that version is vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug.