# psycopg2 error saying image not found while compiling in virtual env

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "db_create.py", line 6, in <module>
db.create_all()
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 895, in create_all
self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site- packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 887, in _execute_for_all_tables
op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 833, in get_engine
return connector.get_engine()
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 499, in get_engine
self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 362, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 74, in create
dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 462, in dbapi
import psycopg2
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Reason: image not found
```

I am using postgreAPP and i even checked out other peoples problems here like 
[psycopg2 installation error - Library not loaded: libssl.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365619/psycopg2-installation-error-library-not-loaded-libssl-dylib/21309011#21309011)

the lib file is in this folder on my pc

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

but still cant find a solution.

Comment: You say that you tried the other solutions, does that mean you tried running `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/` or did you run the exact command from the answer you linked to?

Comment: yup I tried that dint work for some reason but I just saw this other post saying `sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib`
which actually worked, thanks though.