# Where are ini files on MacOsX Sierra?

Tags: php, macos-sierra

I've just bought new MacBook Pro. Take a look on what `php -i | grep ini` returns:

```
prompt> php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
Supported handlers => ndbm cdb cdb_make inifile flatfile
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
open sourced by => Epinions.com
```

And this is what happens when I run `php --ini`

```
prompt> $ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

It seems there current php is not loading any php.ini file. Is it possible?

Comment: What does `php --ini` show?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Check this question; essentially, there should be a php.ini.default file within `/etc` or `/private/etc`; copy that to `/etc/php.ini` or `/private/etc/php.ini`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19827495/899126

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Current versions of Mac OS X do not ship with a `php.ini`. PHP uses internal defaults for all settings.

There is a sample configuration file installed at `/etc/php.ini.default`. If you need to customize PHP settings, you can use that file as a template to create a configuration file at `/etc/php.ini`. PHP will read settings from that file if it's present.

Comment: Where you found this information? Where is possibile to find all about new php configuration of a new MacOs version?

Comment: I just downloaded php7.0 for Mac and there IS an ini file that ships with it named php-7.0.ini. I guess you copy it to /etc/php.ini for it to take effect

Comment: If I create php.ini in /etc/ directory it all the configuration setting will be use from this or /etc/php.ini.default will be the fallback file for that ?

Answer (score 28):

Edit: The following method was tested and I confirm it works on macOS, Linux and Windows' CMD and Bash

All you need to type in the terminal/CMD/Bash is

```
php --ini
```

It will render something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a PHP function called php_ini_loaded_file() which returns the path of php.ini which is loaded.

Try the code below.

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>
```

Comment: You will have to rename the file /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command to search the file system for php.ini or anything else.  It can take a long time to find it, depending on your file system size. If you want to make it stop searching you can do `CTRL-C`.

```
find / -type f -name php.ini
```

If you're not root you'll get some permission denied messages, if you want to run as root you can do this.

```
sudo find / -type f -name php.ini
```

Here's a tutorial for find if you're interested in some other examples.

http://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/

Answer (score 2):

```
php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();"
```

on my machine returns:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
```

;)

Answer (score 2):

I'll add an updated answer for anyone dealing with this on MacOS Mojave and PHP 7.1

Running `php --ini` in the terminal returned this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I found the `php.ini.default` file in `/private/etc/`, duplicated it and renamed it to `php.ini`, which now gets loaded properly:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in MacOS Sierra with PHP 7.1 installed:

1. Create a php file called phpinfo_temp.php (remember to remove this file when you're done):

   `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Load the file and you'll notice about 7 variables down: "Loaded Configuration File:". This is the php file that is loaded.
3. Backup the php.ini file before editing:

   `sudo cp /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini.backup`
4. Then edit php.ini

   `sudo nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`
5. Once you're done editing, restart the apache server

   `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

most often the `.ini` file doesn't exist as is, but it is named `.ini.default` in the `/etc`.