# phppgadmin not workig after update to mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, phppgadmin

Before updating to mavericks on my mac book pro. I was using phpmyadmin and phppgadmin without problems. After upgrading to mavericks   `http://localhost/~burakk/phppgadmin/`  gives me error:

Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.

I could make  `http://localhost/~burakk/phpmyadmin/`  work but phppgadmin does not work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavericks upgrade installs php 5.4 and your php.ini is reset to default, which doesn't include Postgres. 
See the question:
[Enabling PostgreSQL support in PHP on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I have done the steps... But i am still getting the same error

Comment: Does phpInfo() show pgsql as installed?. I found that Ihad to copy php.ini.default to php.ini - I'm positive that I ddin't do that previously. Good Luck!

Comment: No it does not shown as installed. In my private/etc/  folder there is no php.ini but there is php.ini.default ?

Comment: cd /private/etc
sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini It seems that the earlier edition used to go to the default copy if php.ini wasn't found

Comment: Sorry i forgot to get rid of the ; character before extension=pgsql.so  Now everything works as expected...