# PHP/PGSQL configured and running on Mavericks (10.9) but pdo_pgsql won't configure

Tags: php, macos, pdo, osx-mavericks, php-pgsql

I've just upgraded to MacOS Mavericks (10.9) and I'm using the Postgres.app install.

I followed the instructions in the answer to [Enabling PostgreSQL support in PHP on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x) to make PGSQL accessible again. I included the --with-pgsql=/path/to/pgsql option to address the "Cannot find libpq-fe.h" error and pgsql access is successfully enabled.

However, when I came to configuring **pdo_pgsql** I got the "Cannot find libpq-fe.h" error despite specifying the install path exactly as I did in the **pgsql** configuration above.

Here's a snip from the successful **pgsql** config - note the double slash in the **pg_config check** response.

```
pgsql$ ./configure --with-pgsql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/
<...>
checking for pg_config... /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin//pg_config
<...>
```

'pg_config' is where it should be:

```
$ ls /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_conf*
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

**But**, when configuring **pdo_pgsql**, pg_config is not found at all.

```
pdo_pgsql$ ./configure --with-pgsql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/
<...>
checking for pg_config... not found
configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path
```

I have tried specifying the path with and without trailing slash, and with or without the bin directory, all of which work with **pgsql** and none of which work with **pdo_pgsql**.

Comment: Hmm... I checked that out, but don't see the link to PDO being unavailable on a successful working installation of PHP/PGSQL. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php) say that the option for the PDO_PGSQL driver is `--with-pdo-pgsql[=DIR]'

Comment: Milen: Thanks! I'm so embarrassed - I'd just returned to this page to make this note after looking at the header of the configure script. "Read the doc first!"

Answer (score 2):

```
$./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4
```

It worked for me.

Comment: checking for PDO includes... checking for PDO includes... 
configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I tried to run your suggested command