# phppgadmin not found? (mac os x)

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks, phppgadmin

I tried installing/enabling phppgadmin on my mac following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x) guy's tutorial (one of the answers), and after doing it step by step it's still not working. Whenever I try to access localhost/phppgadmin it says "The requested URL /phppgadmin was not found on this server."

Any guesses on what should I do next?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I managed to change a few things and now whenever I access localhost/phppgadmin I get this message: "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option." I tried recompiling it and I'm still getting this.

Comment: whatever you did in your webserver's setup is wrong, and the admin stuff is not where it should be.

Comment: I keep getting this message now, what can I do? "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option."

Comment: LOL - You're way ahead of me; I didn't even know what URL to use. Unfortunately, that URL gives me the message The requested URL /phppgadmin was not found on this server. I'm finding PostgreSQL incredibly geeky (i.e. not user-friendly in the least). Sorry I can't give you any tips, but I'm probably going to either hire someone to install and configure it for me (better than spending more time beating my brains out) or just stick with MySQL.