# php artisan migrate : PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo, laravel-5

I was in need to install Php 5.6 with postgres. I followed the instructions [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706027/install-php-with-postgresql-on-mac-using-homebrew) and did:

```
brew install php56 --without-mysql --without-apache --with-postgresql
brew install php56-pdo-pgsql
```

`Php 5.6` and `postgres` are running fine with my Projects using PostgreSQL.

Now there is some problem with `Laravel` projects using `mysql`. On running `php artisan migrate` command, it shows:

```
[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

Project works fine in the browser though. Data is being fetched perfectly from the mysql tables. `php -m` also does not shows `mysql`. But `phpinfo` does shows `mysql` module.

What could be the problem? Do i need to reinstall mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you would need to activate mysql extension in php
Find your php.ini. Create a php file with following content and run it.
 It will tell you where it is.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Just look at the path of loaded configuration file. Common places include /etc/apache/, /etc/php4/apache2/php.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or even /usr/local/lib/php.ini for Windows it may be C:\Users\username\PHP\php.ini

Edit your server’s php.ini and look for the following line. Remove the ‘;’ from the start of the line and restart Apache. Things should work fine now!

```
;extension=mysql.so
```

should become

```
extension=mysql.so
```

For windows it will be

```
;extension=mysql.dll
```

should become

```
extension=mysql.dll
```

Restart your apache service to load the new configuration.