# When I want to see my php version, use the command "php -v", there show some warnings. How to solve it?

Tags: php

When I want to see my php version, use the command `php -v`, there show some warnings. How to solve it?

[image]

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_pgsql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_pgsql.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_pgsql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/pdo_pgsql.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling PostgreSQL support in PHP on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a php configuration file that try to loads the `pdo_pgsql.so` library, but the library isn't installed correctly.

You can either disable the library loading by removing the configuration directive loading it (you should have something like this:`extension=pdo_pgsql.so`) or install the pdo for php correctly.